# Open Exchange Rates API usage

Tags: jquery, json

I'm looking at an API here:

https://openexchangerates.org/documentation

The call is:

`http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID`

And the return is:

```
{
"disclaimer": "Exchange rates provided by [...]",
"license": "Data collected and blended [...]",
"timestamp": 1319730758,
"base": "USD",
"rates": {
    "AED": 3.672626,
    "AFN": 48.3775,
    "ALL": 110.223333,
    "AMD": 409.604993,
    /* 160 fx rates available - see currencies.json */
    "YER": 215.035559,
    "ZAR": 8.416205,
    "ZMK": 4954.411262,
    "ZWL": 322.355011
}
}
```

My question here is, how do I use this to display the INR rate which is returned? In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/4AKaJ/), I've only got as far as calling the API with my App ID which needs to be displayed in the `<span class="display">`. I'm not very fluent with JSON and it's associated functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `data.rates.INR`?

Comment: I think so. I've updated my fiddle, is this correct? It returns the value as an alert. http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/4AKaJ/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jason object can be accessed just like a normal object in javascript. In this case you can use:

```
data.rates.INR
```

To get that into your span, do this

```
$('.display').html( data.rates.INR)
```

inside your function

lastly, don't forget to change your fiddle to have jQuery as the framework over on the left

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AKaJ/5/)